# apply using a function with iloc pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-apply

I have a data set with 40 columns and I want to define a function that operate the columns.

For example,

```
p = {'val1': [10, 20, 30, 40],
    'val2': [15, 25, 35, 45]}

data = pd.DataFrame(p, columns=['val1', 'val2'])
data
```

I have this data and I did the following operation

```
inc = 100*((data.iloc[:, -1]/ data.iloc[:, -1-1])-1)
inc
```

the result is

```
0    50.000000
1    25.000000
2    16.666667
3    12.500000
dtype: float64
```

I want select the max and the index of the max value, I did the following

```
(inc.idxmax(), max(inc))
```

I obtained the following result

```
(0, 50.0)
```

Now, I define a function

```
def increase(column):
    inc = 100*((data.iloc[:, -column]/ data.iloc[:, -column-1])-1)
    return (inc.idxmax(), max(inc))
```

I select the columns backwards.

and I want to apply this function to all my columns

```
new_data = data.apply(increase)
```

when I use this I got the error

```
IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds
```

and if I use applymap I got the same error

What can I do?

Comment: replace wdi_gdp with data

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need to apply the function increase if you already have the result of the df: index 0 - value: 50. Share your expected result.

Comment: wdi_gdp is the data. I need apply the function because in the original data I have 40 columns and I need operate all the columns with that function.

Comment: hey, 1. what is your expected outcome of all process. 2.can you add one more column so we see how you want to refer to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to use multiple columns in the function.
The apply is not the solution here because it's working on one row or column (axis=0 or 1) at the time.

so my suggestion is to us for and enter 2 columns per iteration that way:

```
def increase(col1,col2):
   inc = 100*((col2/ col1)-1)
   return (inc.idxmax(), max(inc))

lst = []
for i in range(len(data.columns)):
    j=i+1
    if j<len(data.columns):
        col1 = data[data.columns[i]]
        col2 = data[data.columns[j]]
        lst.append(increase(col1,col2))

pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

[image]